# iOS/AVFoundation: Design pattern for asynch handlers when turning arrays of images into tracks and then into a single video?

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, avfoundation

Can you point me to design pattern guides to adapt my style to AVFoundation's asynch approach?

Working an app where you create an image and place audio onto hotspots on it. I'm implementing export to a movie that is the image with effects (glow of hotspot) playing under the audio.

I can reliably create the video and audio tracks and can correctly get audio into an AVMutableComposition and play it back. Problem is with the video. I've narrowed it to my having written a synchronous solution to a problem that requires use of AVFoundation's asynch writing methods.

The current approach and where it fails (each step is own method):

1. Create array of dictionaries. 2 objects in dictionary. One dictionary object is image representing a keyframe, another object is URL of audio that ends on that keyframe. First dictionary has start keyframe but not audio URL.
2. For each dictionary in the array, replace the UIImage with an array of start image->animation tween images->end state image, with proper count for FPS and duration of audio.
3. For each dictionary in the array, convert image array into a soundless mp4 and save using [AVAssetWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler], then replace image array in dictionary with URL of mp4. Each dictionary of mp4 & audio URL represents a segment of final movie, where order of dictionaries in array dictates insert order for final movie

-- all of above works, stuff gets made & ordered right, vids and audio playback --

1. For each dictionary with mp4 & audio URL, load into AVAssets and insert into an AVMutableComposition track, one track for audio & one for video. The audio load & insert works, plays back. But the video fails and appears to fail because step 4 starts before step 3's AVAssetWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler finishes for all MP4 tracks.

One approach would be to pause via while loop and wait for status on the AVAssetWriter to say done. This smacks of working against the framework. In practice it is also leading to ugly and sometimes seemingly infinite waits for loops to end.

But simply making step 4 the completion handler for finishWritingWithCompletionHandler is non-trivial because I am writing multiple tracks but I want step 4 to launch only after the last track is written. Because step 3 is basically a for-each processor, I think all completion handlers would need to be the same. I guess I could use bools or counters to change up the completion handler, but it just feels like a kluge.

If any of the above made any sense, can someone give me/point to a primer on design patterns for asynch handling like this? TIA.

Answer (score 3):

You can [use GCD dispatch groups](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW19) for that sort of problem.
From the docs:

> Grouping blocks allows for aggregate synchronization. Your application
>   can submit multiple blocks and track when they all complete, even
>   though they might run on different queues. This behavior can be
>   helpful when progress can’t be made until all of the specified tasks
>   are complete.

The basic idea is, that you call [dispatch_group_enter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_group_enter) for each of your async tasks. In the completion handler of your tasks, you call [dispatch_group_leave](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_group_leave).

Dispatch groups work similar to counting semaphores. You increment a counter (using dipsatch_group_wait) when you start a task, and you decrement a counter when a task finishes. 
[dispatch_group_notify](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_group_notify) lets you install a completion handler block for your group. This block gets executed when the counter reaches 0.

This blog post provides a good overview and a complete code sample: http://amro.co/post/48248949039/using-gcd-to-wait-on-many-tasks

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I can't get dispatch_group_wait to actually wait though. I put a description in the new answer below, because of formatting issues in this comment section.

Answer (score 0):

@weichsel Thank you very much. That seems like it should work. But, I'm using dispatch_group_wait and it seems to not wait. I've been banging against it for several hours since you first replied but now luck. Here's what I've done:

- Added property that is a dispatch group, called videoDispatchGroup, and call dispatch_group_create in the init of the class doing the video processing
- In the method that creates the video tracks, use dispatch_group_async(videoDispatchGroup, dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{ [videoWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^{
- The video track writing method is called from a method chaining together the various steps. In that method, after the call to write the tracks, I call   dispatch_group_wait(videoProcessingGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
- In the dealloc, call dispatch_release(videoDispatchGroup)

That's all elided a bit, but essentially the call to dispatch_group_wait doesn't seem to be waiting. My guess is it has something to do with the dispatch_group_asyn call, but I'm not sure exactly what.

I've found another means of handling this, using my own int count/decrement via the async handler on finishWritingWithCompletion handler. But I'd really like to up my skills by understanding GCD better.

---

Here's the code-- dispatch_group_wait never seems to fire, but the movies themselves are made. Code is elided a bit for brevity, but nothing was removed that doesn't work without the GCD code.

```
@implementation MovieMaker 

// This is the dispatch group
@synthesize videoProcessingGroup = _videoProcessingGroup;

-(id)init {
  self = [super init];

  if (self) {
     _videoProcessingGroup = dispatch_group_create();
  }

  return self;
}

-(void)dealloc {
  dispatch_release(self.videoProcessingGroup);
}

-(id)convert:(MTCanvasElementViewController *)sourceObject {
  // code fails in same way with or without this line
  dispatch_group_enter(self.videoProcessingGroup);

  // This method works its way down to writeImageArrayToMovie
  _tracksData = [self collectTracks:sourceObject];

  NSString *fileName = @"";

  // The following seems to never stop waiting, the movies themselves get made though
  // Wait until dispatch group finishes processing temp tracks
  dispatch_group_wait(self.videoProcessingGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

  // never gets to here
  fileName = [self writeTracksToMovie:_tracksData];

  // Wait until dispatch group finishes processing final track
  dispatch_group_wait(self.videoProcessingGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

  return fileName;
}


// @param videoFrames should be NSArray of UIImage, all of same size
// @return path to temp file
-(NSString *)writeImageArrayToMovie:(NSArray *)videoFrames usingDispatchGroup:(dispatch_group_t)dispatchGroup {
// elided a bunch of stuff, but it all works

  AVAssetWriter *videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:result]
                                                     fileType:AVFileTypeMPEG4
                                                        error:&error];

//elided stuff

  //Finish the session:
  [writerInput markAsFinished];


  dispatch_group_async(dispatchGroup, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [videoWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^{
      dispatch_group_leave(dispatchGroup);

// not sure I ever get here? NSLogs don't write out.
      CVPixelBufferPoolRelease(adaptor.pixelBufferPool);
    }];
  });

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi Rod - Sorry for the late reply :) I didn't see your answer as I only receive notifications for comments. 
It seems you never call dispatch_group_enter - This is crucial as it increments the wait counter. If you never "enter" a group, dispatch_group_wait has no effect.
I am not sure if your dispatch_group_wait call is in the right location. Probably you can update your answer (or the original question) with code.